# Generating Difficult Classification Data Sets using scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to generate a range of synthetic data sets using make_classification in scikit-learn, with varying sample sizes, prevalences (i.e., proportions of the positive class), and accuracies. Varying the sample size and prevalence is fairly straightforward, but I am having difficult generating any data sets that have less than 50% accuracy using logistic regression. Playing around with the number of informative columns, the number of clusters per class, and the flip_y parameter (which randomly flips the class of a given proportion of observations) seem to reduce the accuracy, but not as much as I would like. Is there a way to vary the parameters of make_classification in such a way to reduce this further (e.g., to 20%)?

Thanks!

Comment: It may be important to know how you actually calculate accuracy here.

Comment: Here, accuracy is binary classification accuracy, that is, (TP + TN) / N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the combination of a fairly low number of `n_samples`, a high probability of randomly flipping the label `flip_y` and a large number of `n_classes` should get you where you want.

You can try the following:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

lr = LogisticRegression()

# 2-class problem
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=100, n_informative=2, flip_y=0.8, random_state=42)

cross_val_score(estimator=lr, X=X, y=y, scoring='accuracy', cv=10)

# Output
array([ 0.54545455,  0.27272727,  0.45454545,  0.2       ,  0.4       ,
        0.5       ,  0.7       ,  0.55555556,  0.55555556,  0.44444444])

# 8-class problem
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=100, n_classes=8, n_informative=4, n_clusters_per_class=1, flip_y=0.5, random_state=42)

cross_val_score(estimator=lr, X=X, y=y, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)

# Output
array([ 0.16666667,  0.19047619,  0.15      ,  0.16666667,  0.29411765])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful! I actually need to stick to binary classification problems, but I will try with smaller samples. I was previously playing around with 1000 - 20000 samples.

Answer (score 1):

In case you go with binary classification only, you should carefully choose `flip_y`. If, for example, you choose `flip_y` to be high, that means you flip almost every label, hence making the problem easier!. (the consistency is preserved)

Hence, in binary classification, `flip_y` is really `min(flip_y,1-flip_y)`, and setting it as 0.5 will make the classification really hard.

Another thing you can do: after creating the data, do dimension reduction, using [PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html):

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

clf = LogisticRegression()

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10000, n_informative=18,n_features=20, flip_y=0.15, random_state=217)
print cross_val_score(estimator=clf, X=X, y=y, scoring='accuracy', cv=4)
#prints [ 0.80287885  0.7904      0.796       0.78751501]

pca = PCA(n_components=10)
X = pca.fit_transform(X)

print cross_val_score(estimator=clf, X=X, y=y, scoring='accuracy', cv=4)
#prints [ 0.76409436  0.7684      0.7628      0.75830332]
```

you can reduce `n_components` to get even poorer results, while having the original number of features:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=1)
X = pca.fit_transform(X)

X = np.concatenate((X, np.random.rand(X.shape[0],19)),axis=1) #concatenating random features
cross_val_score(estimator=clf, X=X, y=y, scoring='accuracy', cv=10)
print cross_val_score(estimator=clf, X=X, y=y, scoring='accuracy', cv=4)
#prints [ 0.5572  0.566   0.5552  0.5664]
```

Getting less than 50% accuracy is 'hard' - even when you take random vectors, the expectancy of accuracy is still 0.5:

```
X = np.random.rand(10000,20)
print np.average(cross_val_score(estimator=clf, X=X, y=y, scoring='accuracy', cv=100))
#prints 0.501489999
```

So 55% accuracy is considered very low.

Comment: @Sean B. is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, thank you! PCA is a good idea, and yes, around 50% seems to be about as low as I can get (I was able to achieve 42% in one case with 100 samples).

Comment: Even though I am late, here is a [good link](https://towardsdatascience.com/https-medium-com-faizanahemad-generating-synthetic-classification-data-using-scikit-1590c1632922)  to generate data of varying difficulty levels using make_classification.